# Unity Pong | Why does my AI Paddle shake?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

Ive implemented an AI paddle that I want to be beatable eventually after you survive long enough. However, right now it currently shakes until the speed of the ball reaches a certain number and im not sure how to fix the shaking. It is a C# Script

```
public class AIPaddle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject theBall;
    public float speed = 10;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (theBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity != Vector2.zero)
        {
            if (theBall.transform.position.y + 0.2 > transform.position.y)
            {
                if (rigidBody.velocity.y < 0) rigidBody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, 1) * speed;
            }
            else if (theBall.transform.position.y + 0.2 < transform.position.y)
            {
                if (rigidBody.velocity.y > 0) rigidBody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, -1) * speed;
            }
            else
            {
                rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0) * speed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because it’s not smoothly changing im guessing it shakes while the ball bounces or if it moves slowly.

Comment: Yea, it mainly happens when the ball moves slowly. I tried implementing a offset but that didnt seem to solve it

Comment: Well your “if” is rather shall we say black and white. If a bit higher go up else if a bit lower go down or all stop. The problem is that’s not a natural action. You need to find a way to change that. Such as sending pressure to the paddle not directly setting all speed up or down or dead stop.

Comment: @BugFinder So like have momentum to the AI paddle is what youre saying?

Comment: Add force  so then it changes direction a little more smoothly.